# Good representation for list of items that can be grouped together

Tags: javascript, data-structures, ui

I am building the frontend of a web app in JavaScript that manages list of past events.  It basically has the following requirements:

- Events are displayed in a vertical list.
- Events can be moved to arbitrary different positions in the list.
- Any event can be "connected" to the event before or after it, by clicking an icon that appears between them.
- When two events are connected, they form a 'group'.
- Connecting further events to a group merges the events into the group.
- Groups move as if they were single items: moving a group moves all the events within that group.
- Groups can also be disconnected by clicking another icon that appears between events, which will split the group into two groups (or individual events, if only one event in a group was left isolated).

How would you structure the data representation of such a system?  i.e. what would the data structure representing the list be, what operations would exist to implement the move and display operations?  I'm talking purely on the frontend here.

My naive idea was that the event list is basically an array, where each element of the array is a union type that can be either a group (which is itself an array) or a single item.  But that seems inelegant in many ways when it comes to the moving, reading, and split operations.  I am wondering if there is a better representation that I have missed that can simplify the implementation of these operations.

Comment: You can use an array of the objects for the same. javascript has large number of functions which will help you for your requirements. You can refer to the following link for the same. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your naive idea is fine. The idea that the same array stores both an "item" data type and a "group" data type will add some case handling, but it is still a valid and *simple* solution.

Array has a rich [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) that solves the moving and splitting that you mentioned.

I'm not sure if you want to implement the UI with vanilla JS or use a 3rd party library, but if you choose a 3rd party library then maybe the choice of the data collection has already been done for you.

Comment: Thanks for that, I might be overthinking this.

Comment: This worked in the end.  I'm not very happy with the number of conditionals in the implementation, but it works.